# How to get data with Linq to XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML. What is the best way to get the data?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Root>
  <EmployeeDataRoot>
    <EmployeeData>
      <Employee_id>123456</Employee_id>
      <Employee_Status>A</Employee_Status>
      <Business_Unit>EN00</Business_Unit>
      <Cost_Center>0904/1992</Cost_Center>
      <Work_Location>DFW</Work_Location>
      <Location>DFW-HDQ1</Location>
      <Job_Category>0003</Job_Category>
      <Last_Name>John</Last_Name>
      <First_Name>Doe</First_Name>
      <Middle_Name />
      <Preferred_Name />
      <Position_Title>Programmer/Analyst</Position_Title>
      <Legal_Entity>EN00</Legal_Entity>
      <Department_Unit>IT HR &amp; Employee Technology</Department_Unit>
      <Run_Date>2016-12-12</Run_Date>
    </EmployeeData>
  </EmployeeDataRoot>
  <Footer_No_of_Records>
    <Records>1</Records>
  </Footer_No_of_Records>
</Root>
```

After looking at some examples online, I tried these two iterations but get an error

> object not set to an instance of an object

I looked over the properties of my `Employee` class as well as the Nodes for any misspellings and didn't see any. I think the error is that I'm not querying the XML properly.

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(file.FullName);
listEmployee = 
    (from e in xDoc.Descendants("EmployeeData") 
      select new Employee
      {
        EmployeeID = e.Element("Employee_ID").Value,
        EmployeeStatus = e.Element("Employee_Status").Value,
        BusinessUnit = e.Element("Business_Unit").Value,
        CostCenter = e.Element("Cost_Center").Value,
        WorkLocation = e.Element("Work_Location").Value,
        Location = e.Element("Location").Value,
        JobCategory = e.Element("Job_Category").Value,
        FirstName = e.Element("First_Name").Value,
        LastName = e.Element("Last_Name").Value,
        LegalEntity = e.Element("Legal_Entity").Value
     }
   ).ToList();
```

and I also tried

```
listEmployee = 
    (from e in xDoc.Element("Root").Elements("EmployeeDataRoot/EmployeeData")
     select new Employee
     {
        EmployeeID = e.Element("Employee_ID").Value,
        EmployeeStatus = e.Element("Employee_Status").Value,
        BusinessUnit = e.Element("Business_Unit").Value,
        CostCenter = e.Element("Cost_Center").Value,
        WorkLocation = e.Element("Work_Location").Value,
        Location = e.Element("Location").Value,
        JobCategory = e.Element("Job_Category").Value,
        FirstName = e.Element("First_Name").Value,
        LastName = e.Element("Last_Name").Value,
        LegalEntity = e.Element("Legal_Entity").Value                                        
    }
  ).ToList();
```

Comment: My spidey sense tells me that `e.Element("Employee_ID")` is null since the element name is `Employee_id`.  These problems will be easier to debug if you put the `Element()` calls on separate lines instead of embedding them in the initialization syntax.  OR add inline null-checking (`e.Element("First_Name") == null ? "" : e.Element("First_Name").Value`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt, ist right, but you write "Employee_ID" wrong. Try this out:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(file.FullName);
listEmployee = 
    (from e in xDoc.Descendants("EmployeeData") 
      select new Employee
      {
        EmployeeID = e.Element("Employee_id").Value,
        EmployeeStatus = e.Element("Employee_Status").Value,
        BusinessUnit = e.Element("Business_Unit").Value,
        CostCenter = e.Element("Cost_Center").Value,
        WorkLocation = e.Element("Work_Location").Value,
        Location = e.Element("Location").Value,
        JobCategory = e.Element("Job_Category").Value,
        FirstName = e.Element("First_Name").Value,
        LastName = e.Element("Last_Name").Value,
        LegalEntity = e.Element("Legal_Entity").Value
     }
   ).ToList();
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. I thought it might be something misspelled and looked them over but of course I missed that one. Thanks for the extra eyes to find that.